# Binary file - Matrix Manipulation

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have several binary files with a known structure (8,12000,real*4). 8 is the number of variables, and 12000 represent the time steps. From these binaries I need to get a final 16x9 matrix defined as followed:

- the first column contains a filename identification.
- on the diagonal are located the extreme values (maxima and minima) of the corresponding variable.
- the simultaneous values of the other variables shall be given in the rows.

At the moment I'm using this code

```
               for i = 1:num_files
    for j = 1:num_ext
        fid = fopen([fullfile(BEGINPATH{1},FILELIST{i}) '.$' VAREXTENSION{j}],'r');
        A = fread(fid,[DLC_dimens{i}{3}(1) DLC_dimens{i}{3}(2)],'real*4');
        for k = 1:size(A,1)
            [max_val(k,i) max_idx(k,i)] = max(A(k,:));
            [min_val(k,i) min_idx(k,i)] = min(A(k,:));
        end
        fclose(fid);
    end
end

% Pre-allocate ULS matrices
uloads = cell(2*size(A,1),size(A,1)+1);
uloads_temp = cell(2*size(A,1),size(A,1)+1);

% Generate ULS matrix for the first file
for i = 1:size(uloads,1)
    uloads{i,end} = DLC_dimens{1}(1);
end

fid = fopen([fullfile(BEGINPATH{1},FILELIST{1}) '.$' VAREXTENSION{1}],'r');
A = fread(fid,[DLC_dimens{i}{3}(1) DLC_dimens{i}{3}(2)],'real*4');


for j = 1:size(uloads,2)-1
    uloads{1,j} = A(j,max_idx(1,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{2,j} = A(j,min_idx(1,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{3,j} = A(j,max_idx(2,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{4,j} = A(j,min_idx(2,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{5,j} = A(j,max_idx(3,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{6,j} = A(j,min_idx(3,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{7,j} = A(j,max_idx(4,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{8,j} = A(j,min_idx(4,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{9,j} = A(j,max_idx(5,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{10,j} = A(j,min_idx(5,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{11,j} = A(j,max_idx(6,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{12,j} = A(j,min_idx(6,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{13,j} = A(j,max_idx(7,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{14,j} = A(j,min_idx(7,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{15,j} = A(j,max_idx(8,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
    uloads{16,j} = A(j,min_idx(8,1))*DLC_dimens{1}{4};
end
fclose(fid);

% ULS temporary matrix generation
uls = uloads;

for i = 2:num_files
    fid = fopen([fullfile(BEGINPATH{1},FILELIST{i}) '.$' VAREXTENSION{1}],'r');
    A = fread(fid,[8 12000],'float32');
    for j = 1:size(uloads,1)
        uloads_temp{j,9} = DLC_dimens{i}(1);
    end
    for k = 1:size(uloads,2)-1
        uloads_temp{1,k} = A(k,max_idx(1,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{2,k} = A(k,min_idx(1,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{3,k} = A(k,max_idx(2,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{4,k} = A(k,min_idx(2,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{5,k} = A(k,max_idx(3,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{6,k} = A(k,min_idx(3,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{7,k} = A(k,max_idx(4,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{8,k} = A(k,min_idx(4,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{9,k} = A(k,max_idx(5,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{10,k} = A(k,min_idx(5,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{11,k} = A(k,max_idx(6,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{12,k} = A(k,min_idx(6,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{13,k} = A(k,max_idx(7,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{14,k} = A(k,min_idx(7,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{15,k} = A(k,max_idx(8,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
        uloads_temp{16,k} = A(k,min_idx(8,i))*DLC_dimens{i}{4};
    end
    if uloads_temp{1,1}(:) > uls{1,1}(:)
        uls(1,:) = uloads_temp(1,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{2,1}(:) < uls{2,1}(:)
        uls(2,:) = uloads_temp(2,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{3,2}(:) > uls{3,2}(:)
        uls(3,:) = uloads_temp(3,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{4,2}(:) < uls{4,2}(:)
        uls(4,:) = uloads_temp(4,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{5,3}(:) > uls{5,3}(:)
        uls(5,:) = uloads_temp(5,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{6,3}(:) < uls{6,3}(:)
        uls(6,:) = uloads_temp(6,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{7,4}(:) > uls{7,4}(:)
        uls(7,:) = uloads_temp(7,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{8,4}(:) < uls{8,4}(:)
        uls(8,:) = uloads_temp(8,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{9,5}(:) > uls{9,5}(:)
        uls(9,:) = uloads_temp(9,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{10,5}(:) < uls{10,5}(:)
        uls(10,:) = uloads_temp(10,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{11,6}(:) > uls{11,6}(:)
        uls(11,:) = uloads_temp(11,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{12,6}(:) < uls{12,6}(:)
        uls(12,:) = uloads_temp(12,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{13,7}(:) > uls{13,7}(:)
        uls(13,:) = uloads_temp(3,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{14,7}(:) < uls{14,7}(:)
        uls(14,:) = uloads_temp(14,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{15,8}(:) > uls{15,8}(:)
        uls(15,:) = uloads_temp(15,:);
    end

    if uloads_temp{16,8}(:) < uls{16,8}(:)
        uls(16,:) = uloads_temp(16,:);
    end
    fclose(fid);
end
```

Now comes the question: I was thinking of a procedure where

1. I generate a temporary uloads_temp matrix just with the first file;
2. Calculate the uloads matrix for the i-th file (i = 2:num_files)
3. Compare the terms on the diagonal between i-th uloads matrix and temporary uloads_temp:
   a) if the elements of the i-th ulaods are major (minor) than the respective uloads_temp values
   b) update uloads_temp rows the condition a) occurs.

I hope I explained everything properly. Could you please give me a hint on how to perform the described loops?

I thank you all in advance.

WKR,
Francesco

P.S. : everything could be reproduced by means fo matrices filled of random numbers; I just copied and pasted my code with reference to a file list.

Comment: I did not dive into your code, but if you can do it for one file, then why don't you just do it for each file individually and combine the results afterwards?

Comment: because I don't wanna run out of memory. Storing would be memory-consuming. at least I would think so.

Comment: It depends on how many files you have, if there are only 100 or so it should not be a problem: storing  `num2cell(rand(12000,8,100));` does not consume that much memory. Otherwise your procedure does not sound like a bad idea.

Comment: Unfortunately the number of files is not pre-determined. But usually it's around two thousand or so. Storing each matrix would require less coding effort, but I'd like to get a good solution in terms of speed and memory-saving.

Comment: I am having some trouble reproducing the problem, could you edit your code to become a working example? For example replace A by random numbers?